# modulo with unsigned int

Tags: c++, random, modulo, prng

In C++ i try to use modulo operator for two unsigned int variables like in Marsaglia's multiply with carry algorithm.
The results seem right, but i'm not sure about the limitations of modulo.

```
m_upperBits = (36969 * (m_upperBits & 65535) + (m_upperBits >> 16))<<16;
m_lowerBits = 18000 * (m_lowerBits & 65535) + (m_lowerBits >> 16);
unsigned int sum = m_upperBits + m_lowerBits;  /* 32-bit result */
unsigned int mod = (max-min+1);
int result=min+sum%mod;
```

Comment: `usigned int` is not guaranteed to have exactly 32 bits. Btw, what's the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are not unsure of

Comment: What are "limitations of modulo"?

Comment: ok so there is no problem with using types up to 32bit as long as they both have the same range?

Comment: There is no problems with modulo. Wrt types, I would STRONGLY recommend to use explicitly sized types for such code. `#include <cstddef> ... uint32_t sum = ...; uint32_t mod = ...;`

Answer (score 0):

Reference: C++03 paragraph 5.6 clause 4

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator  yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined; 
>   otherwise (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a. If both operands are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative; if not, the sign of the remainder is implementation-defined.

I don't see any limitations of modulo in c.